# Issue with where clause in active record class

Tags: codeigniter

`$params['title']` is a string and `$params['feed']` is an integer. Column's 'title' type is `varchar` and column's 'feed' type is `integer`. The PHP code is:

```
$this->db->where('title', $params['title']);
$this->db->where('feed', $params['feed']);
$query = $this->db->get('news');
```

So everything should be fine, BUT...

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'riots: intense anger after deaths of three young men AND `feed` = '1'' at line 3
SELECT * FROM (`news`) WHERE `title` = Birmingham riots: intense anger after deaths of three young men AND `feed` = '1'
Filename: C:\path\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Of course, it's obvious why an error occurred. Is there any way to fix it (apart from not using active record class)? Looked at CI's documentation, but have no idea why this problem occurred.

**EDIT**

Solved by changing to

```
$this->db->where('title', (string) $params['title']);
```

And other clause accordingly. And now have a bunch of identical errors in other models. Well, I guess the only solution is to add var type everywhere manually.

Comment: Where are you assigning `$params['title']` and what version of codeigniter are you running?

Comment: Initially the value is assigned in other model

    $data['title'] = $item->title;

The object   $item is created by SimpleXML class. And then array    $data is passed as an argument to the model's method (where the error occurs).
CI version is the newest, 2.0.2.

Comment: looks like this SimpleXML class's `title` property isn't a string.

Comment: Yes, you are right. gettype() returns 'object'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this SimpleXML class's `title` property isn't a string.

You could simply cast it to a string as soon as you get it, instead of waiting until you do the insert.

```
data['title'] = (string) $item->title;
```